# Lookup Search Page Incomplete match behaviour

Tags: lookup, global-search, search-layout

I've encountered an issue with the lookup search in Case object. I have lookup field into custom field product__c.
When I search incomplete keyword like 'park' it doesn't display any results, but 'parkett' does. Do lookups require a complete match? I couldn't find this limitation specified.
What if the user wants to search for entries starting with something incomplete like 'park'

[image]

[image]